# Работа с датами формата dd.mm.yyyy SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

Есть таблица, в которой нужно считать разницу дат, которые приведены в формате dd.mm.yyyy. Но SQL, на сколько я понял, умеет оперировать только с форматом yyyy-mm-dd. Что делать?

Comment: Простите, это даты ХРАНЯТСЯ в таком формате (в поле VARCHAR, вероятно), или они просто так ОТОБРАЖАЮТСЯ в некоем клиенте?

Comment: @Akina таблица импортируется из csv, в котором даны в таком дормате

Comment: Да какая разница, откуда и в каком виде данные импортятся? Главное - в каком формате они ХРАНЯТСЯ в таблице. Типы полей - какие?

Comment: @Akina, [в SQLite отсутствует полноценная поддержка DATETIME](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html). Т.е. ХРАНЯТСЯ они в таблице как текст даже если указать тип DATE.

Comment: @MaxU А какая разница, есть специальный тип или нет? `TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS")` - пожалуйста, есть, и литерал в этом формате при использовании как литерал даты (например, в качестве аргумента функции julianday) будет правильно понят сервером. А вот формата `dd.mm.yyyy` в списке понимаемых сервером нет. И если автор использовал именно его для хранения данных - то кто ему злобный Буратин?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
sqlite> create table aaa(dt date);
sqlite> insert into aaa values('01.01.2017');
sqlite> insert into aaa values('30.01.2017');
sqlite> insert into aaa values('28.02.2017');
sqlite> select * from aaa;
dt
----------
01.01.2017
30.01.2017
28.02.2017
sqlite> select julianday('now') - julianday(substr(dt, 7, 4)||'-'||substr(dt, 4, 2)||'-'||substr(dt, 1, 2)) from aaa;
julianday('now') - julianday(substr(dt, 7, 4)||'-'||substr(dt, 4, 2)||'-'||substr(dt, 1, 2))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
73.7166386689059
44.7166386689059
15.7166386689059
```

[из документации](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html):

> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates
> and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite
> are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER
> values:
>
> - **TEXT** as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
> - **REAL** as Julian
>   day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November
>   24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar.
> - **INTEGER**
>   as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.
>
> Applications can chose to store dates and times in any of these
> formats and freely convert between formats using the [built-in date
> and time functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь SELECT (JulianDay(eventend) - JulianDay(eventstart))

Comment: juliandate принимает формат yyyy-mm-dd, на сколько я осведомлен и в любом другом случае возвращает null

Comment: @sm4ll_3gg да, бы не прав, получается единственный выход - пилить хранение