# Как сделать выборку за определенное количество дней?

Tags: python, sqlite, дата, datetime, sqlite3

Есть таблица `stats` в которой есть столбец `date` с типом данных `TEXT`. Дата записывается туда в формате dd-mm-YY (01-01-2020), делается это таким образом:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
sql.execute("INSERT INTO stats VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", 
    (authorid, messageId, author, str(now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))))
db.commit()
```

Как сделать выборку за последних 30 дней?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[В SQLite нет "настоящего" типа данных `DATE`](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) - данные типа DATE/TIME могут храниться в одном из следующих видов:

- строк/`text` (обычно используют ISO8601: `"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS"`)
- целых чисел (UNIX epoch - число секунд прошедших с `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`)
- вещественных чисел (as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar).

Соответственно, при использовании строк при сравнении будет использоваться [лексикографическое сравнение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/489888/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82). Например, `"2" > "1999999"`, т.к. первый символ первой строки (двойка) больше единицы, первого символа во второй строке.

Это одна из причин [почему в SQLite надо хранить дату/время только в одном из следующих форматов](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

- YYYY-MM-DD
- YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
- YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
- YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS
- YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM
- YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
- YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS
- HH:MM
- HH:MM:SS
- HH:MM:SS.SSS
- now
- DDDDDDDDDD

Пример:

```
sqlite> create table test(id integer not null primary key autoincrement, date text);
sqlite> insert into test(date) values('2020-08-01');
sqlite> insert into test(date) values('2020-08-02');
sqlite> insert into test(date) values('2020-08-15');
sqlite> insert into test(date) values('2020-09-01');
sqlite> insert into test(date) values('2020-09-10');
sqlite> select * from test;
id          date
----------  ----------
1           2020-08-01
2           2020-08-02
3           2020-08-15
4           2020-09-01
5           2020-09-10
sqlite> select * from test where date >= date('now', '-30 days');
id          date
----------  ----------
4           2020-09-01
5           2020-09-10
```

#### Вывод: если вам нужен другой формат даты, то форматируйте его *только для вывода*, но не для хранения.

---

В [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/639984/211923) показано как можно работать с датами, сохраненными в нестандартном для SQLite формате (`dd.mm.yyyy`) - как у вас в вопросе. Но для любой операции с датами вам сначала придется парсить строку в дату - это очень неэффективно и не имеет смысла.

**Внимание** в ответе по ссылке используется <s>ненормативная лексика</s> шаманский бубен. ;)

Answer (score 1):

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/4429028/10941639
>
> > Sqlite [doesn't have a date type](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/32457534/10941639
>
> > Sqlite can not compare on dates. we need to convert into seconds and cast it as integer.

```sql
SELECT * FROM stats WHERE cast(strftime('%s', substr(date, 7) || '-' || substr(date, 4, 2) || '-' || substr(date, 1, 2)) AS integer) BETWEEN cast(strftime('%s', 'now', '-30 days') AS integer) AND cast(strftime('%s', 'now') AS integer)
```

Получилось отвратительно. Надеюсь, кто-нибудь предложит решение лучше.